# java.sql.SQLException:path

Tags: java, database, sqlite, launch4j

I got this error when I changed my java project into an .exe file and then I try it in another PC [The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wy8O.png)
here is the code of connecting to SQLite Database

```
public static Connection dbConnector() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\3542\\Desktop\\DocProject\\DoctorProject.db");
        //JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "connection succesfull");
        return conn;

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to find a way when I transfer my application into another PC my database will work fine 
I am using Eclipse SQLite and Lanuch4j for .exe

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The error says the folder you are using as database source does not exists.

Comment: yes because this path is not available in the other PC , I want to find a way to be able to make my database path dynamically which works at any PC not only my PC

Comment: You need to install the dependencies and move the resources with your executable, in order to make it work...

Answer (score 1):

The path doesn't exist. If you want to run it on other pc's I would recommend you to use relative paths instead of an absolute one.